# Numpy: how to find the best candidate input vector for an output?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I am trying to preprocess my data that comes from a chemical reaction data to fit it in a simple feed forward neural network using Numpy and Python.

[image: data]

Each output (yellow) is assigned to a 2-D array of inputs where each line of every array represent a 1-minute consecutive sample. Each output is sampled each 3 minutes while inputs are assigned each 1 minute.

However I don't want to use a 2-D input array in my neural network as I'm sure I will be over-fitting due to the small size of data I have.

Theoretically, in my chemical experiment, each output should be assigned to one 1-D vector of input only. So I am showing here which might be the possible candidate vectors that should be associated to my output.

My question: Since I don't know which candidate vector I should choose (blue, green, red) to associate it to the output (yellow), how can I find such relationship using Numpy? Is there an algorithm that can let me know that for example the Red combination is the best to associate to my output?

P.S.: The outputs here are equal as to show that all the outputs with the same value should have somehow inputs with very strong correlation but here I did it quickly for the sake of the example.

EDIT: Should I find the correlation between each colored vectors and I pick the strongest correlation?

Comment: In my opinion it would be much more wise to use all the data you have and control the overfitting with regulization. This kind of preprocessing kinda defeats the purpose of using NN's at all (if it's some linear preprocessing you are losing a lot of information; if it's nonlinear it's somewhat as hard as doing the same within the NN).

Comment: @sascha so you suggest it's better to use these vectors i have in some sort of recurrent NNs which is better than manipulating data and losing it right?